# C# async/await issue

Tags: c#, async-await

*Sorry about the question title, I'm not sure about what should it be.*

I have this method:

```
public async Task Instagram(string username, int timeout = 10)
{
    int question = QuestionUtils.GenerateQuestion();
    await DiscordUtils.QuestionAsync(_interactive, _context, question, embed, timeout);

    if (await QuestionUtils.QuestionResponse(question))
        Console.WriteLine("yes");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("no");
}
```

This is what `DiscordUtils.QuestionAsync` looks like:

```
public static async Task QuestionAsync(InteractiveService interactive, SocketCommandContext context, int question, EmbedBuilder embed, int timeout)
{
    await interactive.SendMessageWithReactionCallbacksAsync(
        context, new ReactionCallbackData(null, embed.Build(), false, false, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout))
        .WithCallback(new Emoji("✅"), (_context, _reaction) => QuestionUtils.SetResponse(question, true))
        .WithCallback(new Emoji("❌"), (_context, _reaction) => QuestionUtils.SetResponse(question, false))
    );
}
```

And this is what `QuestionUtils.QuestionResponse` looks like:

```
public static bool QuestionResponse(int question)
{
    while (questions[question] == Response.None)
        Thread.Sleep(100);

    return questions[question] == Response.Yes;
}
```

Basically, my callbacks will get called only once `QuestionUtils.QuestionResponse` will be done (looping).

However, I want them to be called while `QuestionUtils.QuestionResponse` is looping, so by "bypassing" the waiting thing.

So I do not want `DiscordUtils.QuestionAsync` to wait for `QuestionUtils.QuestionResponse` to execute the `QuestionUtils.SetResponse` callbacks.

How could I please do that?

Comment: Any reason for the -1 that was given literally 10 seconds after the question was posted?

Comment: Because [Tim lost his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/245360).

Comment: Not funny, didn't laugh.

Comment: I really don't get why you would check this in a `while` loop.

Comment: Sorry, which for loop are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, it is a `while`.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: @PatrickHofman How else could I do? I am using a while loop in order to only return a result once a response has been set (to something else than ``None``). I agree this doesn't look really clean, but I have no idea about how to do it in an other way.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno This is what I want: I do not want ``DiscordUtils.QuestionAsync`` to wait for ``QuestionUtils.QuestionResponse`` to execute the ``QuestionUtils.SetResponse`` callbacks.

Comment: But it doesn't. DiscordUtils.QuestionAsync gets executed to the end BEFORE QuestionUtils.QuestionResponse

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Exactly, this is what I am saying.

Comment: `bool QuestionResponse(int question)` is not awaitable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Thread.Sleep` when using `async/await` as it blocks the calling thread. Instead use `Task.Delay`:

```
public static async Task<bool> QuestionResponse(int question)
{
    while (questions[question] == Response.None)
        await Task.Delay(100);

    return questions[question] == Response.Yes;
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't seem to be changing anything.

Comment: @Laiteux - You'll need to explain more clearly in your question what the actual issue is, then.

Comment: I do not want ``DiscordUtils.QuestionAsync`` to wait for ``QuestionUtils.QuestionResponse`` to execute the ``QuestionUtils.SetResponse`` callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TaskCompletionSource` to control manually when your `Task` will be completed. Check official docs for example. With right implementation you eventually will end up with something like `await QuestionResponse(1)` or whatever your question ID will be. If you'd like to run multiple `Task`s in parallel and continue when all are done, use `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I can't seem to understand how would this correctly be implemented, having never used it before. Would you please be able to help?

Comment: I barely understand what you're struggling to achieve, so I won't able to rewrite your code. In either case `while` section seems pretty strange to me. You could avoid such things with help of `TaskCompletionSource`. If it isn't what you need, then rewrite your question in a more clear manner.